# how to identify domains, subdomains and bounded contexts in an online retailer integration scenario?

Tags: domain-driven-design

The problem I'm facing is the design of an integration platform.

The company has different tools used for selling online financial services and wants to unify the selling process by creating a common integration platform.

Existing tools range from simply designing a tailor-made offer, to managing all the phases of listing to selling and supporting. The integration platform should orchestrate all the tools.

So I do approach this problem from a DDD point of view?

- Domain: selling online services
- subdomains: service catalog, request offers, sending offers, buying service, support customer.
- bounded context? maybe integration with other company systems like identities and invoices?

My trouble with this is that some existing applications encompass several subdomains, others don't. Also, some applications working in the same subdomain have completely different languages, for example, service vs product, vs project...

How does an integration platform fit in this picture and how would you approach it from a DDD point of view? (or maybe it's a completely wrong approach and should I leave DDD inside each tool and treat them as bounded context?)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend extracting the common bits of meaning (ignoring their names) from the various applications into common domains/bounded contexts.  Each bounded context has anti-corruption layers that essentially adapt the language used in one or more existing applications to the one used in the common domain (and vice versa).  Then you can cut over the existing applications piece-by-piece to use the respective ACLs to take advantage of the common domain implementation.

Eventually, you might even be able to dispense with the ACLs, as the language becomes more ubiquitous, but it's also perfectly okay to keep them around forever: the ACLs introduce some indirection (and possibly complexity, e.g. if they're deployed as their own microservices) but that's the price you pay for limiting coupling to the ACL.

(It's not clear from the question how experienced you are with DDD).

Comment: so you suggest that each "application" has parts that belong to bounded contexts? That could make sense to me, but I can't refactor or redesign existing applications, only ask for minimal changes on API or messaging toward external systems. It's a big company and we are speaking of maybe 10-20 somewhat complex applications.

PS. I'm not very experienced in DDD. I'm actively reading Evans & Vernon books. I've just a feeling that could be a good way to tackle the problem. And from my vague questions I expected some food for thought, like you started to give me.